# How to find all intersections in a Matlab graph?

Tags: matlab, intersection, curve

I have created three graphs: one tangent graph, one negative cotangent graph, and one circle.

Here is what I have so far:

```
%Functions
f1=@(theta1) tan(theta1)
f2=@(theta1) -cot(theta1)
t=linspace(0,2*pi);
x3=4*cos(t);
y3=4*sin(t);

%Plotting
g1=ezplot(f1,[-(5*pi)/2,(5*pi)/2])
hold on
g2=ezplot(f2,[-3*pi,3*pi])
hold on
plot(x3,y3)
grid on
```

I am supposed to find all intersections of the three graphs here, and that's where I am stuck. Thanks for any suggestions if you have any.

Here is the output of my graph:
[image]

Comment: Is it perhaps easiest to do this analytically?

Comment: You can check for every point whether they satisfy the equation of the circle.

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html

Comment: Think outside the box! You know the functions that generated the graph, so you can find where those functions intersect, then you will also know where lines in the graph intersect.